# Which layout to use for desining UI in wpf components?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'am learning wpf. As a part of learning I'm converting a winforms application into a wpf application using mvvm.

In winforms I just dragged and droped. After that I aligned based on my requirement.

But in WPF when i drag and drop a default grid is wrapping the components and I'm facing great difficulty in aligning the components.

On learning the tutorials on wpf https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_layouts.htm

I tried to work with but I don't know which is suitable for my UI.

I want to create UI in wpf as below winform [image]

I have used grid and stackpanel but I have issue with alignment. In grid I have issue with adding new elements in the existing row. In stackpanel I face issue with spacing between the components and aligning the compnent.

Can anyone help me on which panel to use for the above kind of UI.

Answer (score 1):

In general you don't use editors for WPF, you edit the layout XAML by hand and use the visualizer as a guide to show whether or not you've done it right. The Visual Studio editor does let you do things like basic layout, but as soon as you start using ControlTemplates/DataTemplates/Behaviours etc you'll quickly find that it's useless (and believe me, that moment will come much sooner than you think). If you really want to use a graphical editor then Microsoft Blend is your best bet, but even that is generally designed for non-programmers. In fact, in the 10+ years I've been a professional WPF contractor I've yet to encounter a single company that actually uses Blend...or indeed any other GUI-driven XAML editor...for their product development.